# Hadoop hdfs cat pipe edgenode to hdfs

Tags: unix, hadoop, pipe, hdfs, cat

I am trying to send data from the local edgenode to hdfs as a pipe. The purpose is to simulate data coming from an external server going through the edge node hitting a pipe and then landing it in hdfs. This is our requirement. I have tried the below command but it appears to stall out.

```
mkfifo my_pipe
cat mysqlfile.sql my_pipe & cat pipe | hdfs dfs -put /user/bob/test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you `cat` a named pipe it will hang since it waits until the `EOF`.

If you want to do this using pipes, maybe you should try something easier like:

```
cat mysqlfile.sql | hadoop fs -put - /path/you/desire/file.txt
```

You will find some useful information about named pipes, cat and tail on [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139490/continuous-reading-from-named-pipe-cat-or-tail-f).